# Print sum of numbers in Python Script

Tags: python, linux

I've been searching for a while and haven't been able to figure this out.

I'm running Kali Linux and I'm trying to run a very simple script and I'm not getting the output I would expect. I used to programing python on windows and the switch to Kali and I can't get this basic script to give me my desired output.

```
a = 1
b = 2
a + b
```

This should give me the output of 3, however I don't get any output.

When I run:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a + b

print "test %s" %a
```

I get the output:

```
test 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are printing `a` instead of `a + b`. Check with: `print "test %d" % (a+b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saying that you are running the script, I assume that you are not running your code in an interactive shell, which would give you the output you expected. However, while running a script, you have to tell the computer exactly what to do. You missed out the print statement in the first script. So, the computer calculated the sum and happily exited.

Now in the second script, you mistakenely forgot to add before printing out. And, also '%s' is a string  formatter for the type **string** that means it expects a string. Here, we should be using '%d' for a digit(number)

So try either:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b

print "test %d" %c
```

OR DIRECTLY

```
a = 1
b = 2
print "test %d" %(a+b)
```

Comment: Yes, by running the script I'm writing it in GVIM and saving as a .py and then running it in terminal. That's a little different that how I'm used to writing in windows. Generally in windows the first code would assign the variables and have python compute the value of a + b without the need to define c as a variable/equation, and with out the need to tell python to print "c"

Comment: Since you are executing the script via python and not from an interactive environment, you'll have to explicitly print out the result as i showed in the examples above. Do note the change in string formatters and remember to sum them. :)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's going to be a bit of a learning curve from coming from windows. In windows I was able to run that same line of code and receive different results. Thanks!

Comment: In windows you might be running it from the interactive shell.Even in linux if you simply type python in the terminal and then write your code, you'll get the output. I highly doubt that even in windows, if you ran a script outside an interactive python shell, the script gave an output without the print statement.

Comment: Hey, welcome. If I was able to convince you, you could tick the answer I gave. Or you could always wait for more better answers. :)

Comment: It actually does work in windows. I use notepad++ to write my scripts in windows and run them using command prompt. I don't think I've ever used the interactive shell for writing scripts. You're answer worked so it's good enough for me to tick :)

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have two variable a and b assigned with some value and then u are adding a and b, but it has to be stored somewhere; `a+b` doesn't mean the sum of `a` and `b`  goes into `a`!

```
a=10;
b=20;
c=a+b;

print c
```

or

```
a=10;
b=20;
c=a+b;
print "test %d" %c
```

or

```
    a=10;
    b=20;
    c=a+b;
    print "test %d" %(a+b)
```

Comment: Please avoid rhetorical questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Or u can just edit your code to

```
a = 1
b = 2
a += b
print "test %s" %a
```